# How to append at the end of line using VSVIM

Tags: visual-studio, vim, vsvim

I am using vsvim and I think that it is a great tool. 
But I have a problem. It seems the "A" doesn't work when I type 'A' to append at the end of line. Is there any extra configuration required? Or it is just a bug of VSVIM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a feature that's not yet implemented.  The lower case version is but not the upper case one.  I filed issue 245 to track this

- http://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/issue/245

Comment: For everyone else, `A` and `I` are working wonderfully, 2 years later, in VsVim.